# Wrong file version after recent pip install of Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm surprised to have found a file from a different version of a python module I installed with `pip`.

I installed [pyclustering](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering) using

```
pip3 install pyclustering
```

The `kmedoids.py` file on my system (which is part of pyclustering) belongs I believe to version 0.6.6 (it's the same as on this [page](http://pydoc.net/pyclustering/0.6.6/pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids/)), whereas the most recent 0.8 version is as [follows](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/blob/master/pyclustering/cluster/kmedoids.py).

Just for illustration, the 0.6.6 version has this function:

```
def get_medoids(self):
    """!
    @brief Returns list of medoids of allocated clusters.

    @see process()
    @see get_clusters()

    """

    return self.__medoids;
```

while in 0.8 version it is supposed to be:

```
def get_medoids(self):
    """!
    @brief Returns list of medoids of allocated clusters represented by indexes from the input data.

    @see process()
    @see get_clusters()

    """

    return self.__medoid_indexes;
```

I'm pretty sure I have the 0.8 installed, as I tried pip3 show pyclustering
which returned:

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pyclustering
Version: 0.8.0
Summary: pyclustring is a python data mining library
Home-page: https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering
Author: Andrei Novikov
Author-email: pyclustering@yandex.ru
License: GNU Public License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: 
Classifiers:
```

Because I need the version from 0.8, I'm tempted to simply manually replace the file/snippet of codes with the most recent version.

My main questions are:

1. What might be causing this inconsistency?
2. Is there a better way to
   resolve it than manually changing the file?
3. Will the manual change
   cause any issues down the road, e.g. when updating the module via
   pip or otherwise?

Comment: did you use `virtualenv` to have your project installed? and version of dependency is enforced by requrements.txt.

Comment: no i didn't use virtualenv, didn't know that existed, thanks for raising that. not sure I understand your second part about requirements.txt. If I manually change a file from a module, will it get simply overwritten when the module gets updated, or will it cause a conflict or something?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the master branch, not 0.8. The [actual 0.8 code](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/blob/0.8.0/pyclustering/cluster/kmedoids.py#L134) still has `self.__medoids`.

Comment: I see, thx, my mistake. What would you recommend then if the master code is more relevant to me, can I safely swap the files or are there any risks doing so?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the code from the current master which is still in development, you can install the package directly from git repository:

```
$ pip3 uninstall -y pyclustering  # remove the current installation
$ pip3 install git+https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering.git@master
```

or install from the zipfile:

```
$ pip3 install https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to substitute existed 0.8.0 sources by sources on master branch. You need to rebuild core of the library (C++ part of the library, be ready to have compiler that supports C++ 14) that is used by default for processing. Otherwise python code will try to get services from old version of core that may not exist in old version, so crash will be as a consequence.

**First way.** Here is an instruction how to install pyclustering from master branch to separate folder (information from pyclustering Wiki):

```
# download pyclustering from official repository:
mkdir pyclustering
cd pyclustering
git clone https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering.git .

# compile C++ part of the library:
cd ccore
make ccore_x64   # in case of 64-bit python version
# make ccore_x86   # in case of 32-bit python version

# if you don't know which version of python is install then compile both
# make ccore
```

In case of Windows, C++ part of the library can be compiled by the following way:

1. Open 'pyclustering/ccore/' folder.
2. Open solution 'ccore.sln' using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.
3. Choose platform (x64 - for 64-bit, x86 - for 32-bit).
4. Build 'ccore' project.

Add path to 'pyclustering' folder to PYTHONPATH, for example, in case of linux:

```
# return to parent folder of the pyclustering library
cd ../

# add current folder (that is parent folder for pyclustering) to python path
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}
```

If you can't build C++ part of the library it will work anyway, pyclustering detects lack of binaries and will use python implementation only. But I would like to underline that is very dangerous to mix python sources with improper binaries.

**Second way.** You can try already proposed way to install in previous post, but still binary part of the library should be built to make library faster:

```
pip3 uninstall -y pyclustering  # remove the current installation
pip3 install git+https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering.git@master
cd <path_to_pyclustering>/ccore
make ccore_x64 # in case of 64-bit python version
# make ccore_x86   # in case of 32-bit python version

# if you don't know which version of python is install then compile both
# make ccore
```

**Third (bad) way.** Just substitute sources by sources master branch and **remove old binaries**. In this case pyclustering detects lack of core and will use python code only as I already mentioned it above.

```
rm pyclustering/pyclustering/core/x64/linux/ccore.so
rm pyclustering/pyclustering/core/x86/linux/ccore.so
rm pyclustering/pyclustering/core/x64/win/ccore.dll
rm pyclustering/pyclustering/core/x86/win/ccore.dll
```

But this way leads to performance degradation.

Link to pyclustering Wiki page: https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/wiki/Core-of-the-PyClustering